# Excluding Search Terms in Python & Tweepy?

Tags: python, visual-studio, tweepy

I want to search for #gaming, but exclude all tweets that have #stream in them. I'm using Python & Tweepy in Visual Studio Code. I have the below code, but when I run it still includes tweets with #stream. I looked up the Twitter API filtering rules and this is what it had. Could anyone help me with my code? Thanks!

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user2 = api.me()
print(user2.name)

def main():
    search = ("#gaming -#stream")
    numberoftweets = 2
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberoftweets):
        try:
            tweet.favorite()
            tweet.retweet()
            api.create_friendship(tweet.user.id)
            print("Tweet Retweeted and followed")
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
        except StopIteration:
            break
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The search rules are here and checked your search parameters and it seems to be working, so it's not clear where you are seeing #stream. Takes 10-15 seconds to pull 500 tweets and get a hashtag list, but I've run this several times and no #stream. If I remove the - from in front of #stream then hashtag is in the list; works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
search = ("#gaming -#stream")
numberoftweets = 500
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberoftweets)
df_hold_list = [pd.DataFrame([tweet._json.get('entities').get('hashtags')]) for tweet in tweets] # note brackets around json dictionary
df_hashtags = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
df_hashtags.iloc[0]
hashtag_list = df_hashtags.stack().apply(lambda x: '' if pd.isnull(x) else x['text']).unique().tolist()
hashtag_list.sort()
print(hashtag_list)
```